# how put gif image to RAM memory android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, ram

please i have problem with gifview.

I think so what i need is:

I need put my gifimage to RAM memory.

```
package com.paradox02.dell.dormation01;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class GifView extends View{


  //  int pom=0;

    private final static String STORETEXT6="index2.txt";

    public static int indexG2;

    int[] images = {

            R.drawable.troj1,R.drawable.troj2,R.drawable.troj3,R.drawable.troj4,R.drawable.troj5, //0-4
            R.drawable.koc1,R.drawable.koc5,R.drawable.koc3,R.drawable.koc4,R.drawable.koc2,//5-9
            R.drawable.kruh1,R.drawable.kruh2,R.drawable.kruh3, ///10-12
            R.drawable.tutorial1,
            R.drawable.tutorial2,
            R.drawable.tutorial3,
            R.drawable.nic,
    };

    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long movieStart;
    private Integer index2;
    private Context co;

    public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        co = context;
        init(context);

    }

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    co = context;
    init(context);
}

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    co = context;
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setFocusable(true);


    //read();


    gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(images[indexG2]);


    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();

}






@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if(movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = now;
    }

    read();      

   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
            movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
            movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
            movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();

        }
    }).start();
}

    if(gifMovie != null) {

        int dur = gifMovie.duration();
        if(dur == 0) {
            dur = 1000;
        }

        int relTime = (int)((now - movieStart) % dur);

        gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

        gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();
    }
}

public void read() {

    try {

        InputStream in3 = getContext().openFileInput(STORETEXT6);

        if (in3 != null) {

            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in3);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);

            String str;

            StringBuilder buf3 = new StringBuilder();

            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buf3.append(str);

            }

            in3.close();

            indexG2=Integer.valueOf(buf3.toString().trim());



        }

    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

        // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet

    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

}

I try put some code to Thread (runable) to acceleration.

I call this class on Main code:

gifView2 = (GifView2) findViewById(R.id.gif_view2);

```
<com.paradox02.dell.dormation01.GifView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gif_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

app is public on Google Play

[app in GP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paradox02.dell.dormation01)

while I play app sometimes all process crashed and write on display "load Launcher"

Please help me.

Thanks for any suggest.

If you need more code, write => I will put.

Excuse me for my easy English

Comment: Need more info on the actual error.. if you could post the stack trace it would be very helpful :)

Comment: in logcat i can't see error,  i thing so too much work on smartphone but crashed, i want put all images on RAM.

Comment: *"I try put some code to Thread (runable) to acceleration."* This is not how threads work. I would get rid of them unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: yes i try get rid thread but i need put gifpicture save to RAM. i thing so it's problem.

Comment: or try use game and suggest me your therory, what maybe wrong:) 

when i do not use gif animation (static jpg images) app run without problems. then problem is around gifanimations.